# Modify WPF Combobox Usercontrol to work with generic data

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a usercontrol that is essentially an image with a combobox to provide some custom functionality. My current code has the object types hardcoded and I need help/pointers modifying the code to allow this to function on any object data types so I dont have to re-write this code for every combobox with different object types. From what I read online there is no way to make my usercontrol use a generic type . Is there anyway I can refactor this code to get the same result. Here is the result that I am looking for(and currently have). It is basically a combobox with an icon and it allows filtering the drop down based on the values entered.
[image: Result output]

My simplified working code - two object types Fruit and Vegetable that share a IsFruitOrVegetable interface:

```
public class Fruit: IsFruitOrVegetable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public FoodType Type { get; set; }

    public Fruit()
    {
        this.Type = FoodType.Fruit;
    }

    public Fruit(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        this.Type = FoodType.Fruit;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

}


public class Vegetable : IsFruitOrVegetable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public FoodType Type { get; set; }

    public Vegetable()
    {

        this.Type = FoodType.Vegetable;
    }

    public Vegetable(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        this.Type = FoodType.Vegetable;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}

public enum FoodType
{
    None,
    Vegetable,
    Fruit
}

public interface IsFruitOrVegetable
{
    FoodType Type { get; set; }
    string Name { get;set;}
}

public class NoneType : IsFruitOrVegetable
{
    public FoodType Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public NoneType()
    {
        Name = "NotFound";
        Type = FoodType.None;
    }
}
```

Customer object that holds a IsFruitOrVegetable:

```
public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private IsFruitOrVegetable item;

    public IsFruitOrVegetable Item
    {
        get
        {
            return item;
        }
        set
        {
            item = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }
    

    public Customer()
    {
       
    }

    public Customer(string _Name)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        Item = null;
        
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> customersList;

    public ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomersList
    {
        get
        {
            return customersList;
        }
        set
        {
            customersList = value;
        }
    }

    // This is static, so that the ComboBox can revert back to all of the items
    private static ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable> itemsList;

    public static ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable> ItemsList
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsList;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsList = value;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable>();
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Apple"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Banana"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Avocado"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Blueberries"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Fruit("Watermelon"));

        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Broccoli"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Cabbage"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Carrot"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Cauliflower"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Potato"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Cucumber"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Kale"));
        ItemsList.Add(new Vegetable("Bellpepper"));

        CustomersList = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
        CustomersList.Add(new Customer("Bob"));
        CustomersList.Add(new Customer("Tony"));
        CustomersList.Add(new Customer("John"));

        CustomersList[0].Item = ItemsList[0];
        CustomersList[1].Item = ItemsList[1];
        CustomersList[2].Item = ItemsList[2];
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

Usercontrol.xaml:

```xml
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Root}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Image at the side of the ComboBox -->
        <Image Height="30" Width="30" Grid.Column="0">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Type}" Value="{x:Static local:FoodType.Vegetable}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/VegetableIcon.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Type}" Value="{x:Static local:FoodType.Fruit}">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/FruitIcon.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>

        <!-- Actual ComboBox -->
        <ComboBox x:Name="CustomCombo" Grid.Column="1" 
                  IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" KeyDown="CustomCombo_KeyDown"
                  DropDownOpened="CustomCombo_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="CustomCombo_DropDownClosed"
                  IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Name"
                  Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!-- StackPanel consisting of an Image and TextBlock as ItemTemplate-->
                        <Image Height="30" Width="30">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="{x:Static local:FoodType.Vegetable}">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/VegetableIcon.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Value="{x:Static local:FoodType.Fruit}">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/FruitIcon.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

CustomComboBox.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region States
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ItemsSource", 
            typeof(ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable>),
            typeof(CustomComboBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );
    public ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsSource");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedItem",
            typeof(IsFruitOrVegetable),
            typeof(CustomComboBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );
    public IsFruitOrVegetable SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (IsFruitOrVegetable)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return text;
        }
        set
        {
            text = value;

            // Search Function
            if (value != null && value != "")
            {
                var items = new ObservableCollection<IsFruitOrVegetable>();
                foreach (var item in MainViewModel.ItemsList)
                {
                    if (item.Name.ToLower().Contains(Text.ToLower()))
                    {
                        items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                if (items.Count == 0)
                {
                    items.Add(new NoneType());
                }
                ItemsSource = items;
            } else
            {
                ItemsSource = MainViewModel.ItemsList;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("Text");
            RaisePropertyChanged("ItemsSource");
        }
    }
    #endregion
    public CustomComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Sets initial Last Selected Item
        if (SelectedItem != null)
        {
            lastSelectedItem = SelectedItem;
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        var property = PropertyChanged;
        if (property != null)
            property(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    #region Event Handlers
    private IsFruitOrVegetable lastSelectedItem;

    // Saves Last Selected Item when the drop down is opened
    private void CustomCombo_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.IsReadOnly = false;


        if (SelectedItem != null && SelectedItem.Type != FoodType.None)
        {
            lastSelectedItem = SelectedItem;
        }
        Text = "";
    }

    // Validates if Selected Item is of Type None, then it will revert back to 
    // the last selected Item which is saved
    private void CustomCombo_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.IsReadOnly = true;

        if (SelectedItem == null || SelectedItem.Type == FoodType.None)
        {
            if (lastSelectedItem != null)
            {
                SelectedItem = lastSelectedItem;
                Text = SelectedItem.Name;
            } else
            {
                SelectedItem = null;
                Text = "";
            }
        } else if (SelectedItem != null && SelectedItem.Type != FoodType.None)
        {
            Text = SelectedItem.Name;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void CustomCombo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally my view:

```xml
    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="22,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CustomersList,Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Customer" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:CustomComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


    </Grid>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you intend. Since your CustomComboBox seems to require the members of IsFruitOrVegetable interface (odd naming as interface though), I don't think you can modify it to work with _any object data type_ which doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: Your control must not reference the MainViewModel explicitly. To obtain the list, reference the ItemsSource property to which the MainViewModel (or any view model) binds to. Then make the type of ItemsSource `IList<object>` (or `ObservableCollection<object>` if you need to restrict the collection type). You control should not care about data types. Simply remove all the interface related logic and allow your control to handle data items anonymously as plain `object`.

Comment: The interface related logic for example the enum check belongs to the view model which can the set then SelectedItem by configuring a TwoWay binding to the CustomCumboBox.SelectedItem property. This way you will create a reusable and "generic" control that can handle its data items anonymously and is therefore able to handle any data type.

Comment: Same applies to the logic in the Text property's setter: the fact that you need to reference the MainViewModel here to inspect its data tells you that the logic belongs to the MainViewModel. Let the MainViewModel modify its own source collection (which binds to the CustomComboBox.ItemsSource property to update the control implicitly).

Comment: By improving the design as suggested, you will also get rid of the public static MainViewModel members. You would always want to avoid `public static` members as they will easily trick you into bad design, like it happened in your case: if those properties weren't static, you would not be able to design your control the way you did and thus would have created a cleaner design.

Comment: @emoacht exactly. Its currently written to work on IsFruitOrVegetable. I want to make it work on <T>. From what I read online I cant create a usercontrol to work with generic data types. public partial class CustomComboBox<T> : UserControl...

Comment: @BionicCode thanks alot for the suggestions. I will attempt to do what you said. If you dont mind (Im still new to wpf and relatively slow) and if its something thats easy, would you mind putting the modified code (for the user control) with your suggestions to give me a head start and be more helpful. I can attach the entire runnable project if you would like?

Comment: @MElSawy You can't as long as your logic expects the data type to have __Name__ and __Type__ properties. A generic type without any constraint means `System.Object` and it has no such properties. If you set interface constraint to a generic type like `where T : IsFruitOrVegetable`, you can use the generic type but it is virtually same as the current code.

Comment: @emoacht cant I make it a generic object and move some of the specific type code to my viewmodel as BionicCode suggested? Ignore my ignorance I am just thinking out loud as I am not so well versed in WPF/C#

Comment: @MEISawy It depends on your implementation. In general, requiring a generic type to have some constraints is nothing bad. Do you really need a logic which can work with `System.Object`? Probably not.

Comment: @emoacht but if my logic or combobox is type specific this will prevent me of reusing the same tool for other comboboxes too. Not sure if this is the clean way of doing this. Let me know if I am misunderstanding you

Comment: Why can't you use the ComboBox? I don't see any special feature with your CustomComboBox.

Comment: How can I implement having an image beside my text (like an icon)? Also I am implementing two additional features. I am filtering the drop down list based on the text entered into the combobox. I am also showing a "Not found" if the user enters a value not in the list and if he focuses out it returns to the last correct value. I am not aware that the combobox can do this. If it can, I am all ears please. Or rather how can I implement a combobox with these features?